# Powershell command to get Description content in Active Directory

Tags: powershell

Powershell command to get Description content in Active Directory, this is i would like to get   the owner which is not only mentioned in  "ManagedBy" tab also mentioned additional name in Description box.

Comment: the usual way to get the details of what is available from the AD cmdlets is to [1] call the cmdlet with `-Property *` on ONE object to get ALL the props (most are NOT returned by default) [2] assign the output to a $Var, [3] send that to either `Get-Member` or to `Select-Object -Property *` to see all the available items.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am misunderstanding your question:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Description,ManagedBy
```